# Importing a shapefile or geopackage from QGIS 3.16 to MSSQL Server 2019

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I can only find PostGIS, SpatiaLite and Oracle in the database management to import layers to the respective databases.
However, I can connect to MSSQL Server in QGIS and draw and save geometries in it as well. Manual copying of the attribute table also works.

Why can't I save complete layers or shapefiles in MSSQL with QGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drag and drop the layer directly into the database seen in browser. Just have a look to this video:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @eurojam, so I don't have to rely on OGR2OGR in the future. I honestly did not think that the answer is so obvious, which also explains why so little is found about it on the Internet.

Comment: You can also use the Browser2 in QGIS - which is a second Browser widget. Then you can drag and drop files directly from one folder (pick it in Browser2 and drop it into Browser 1) into the database - so no need to load it first into QGIS.